# Integrand is a function of one extra variable, but the definite integral is not. What can one conclude?

Tags: calculus

Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be analytic functions in all their variables.

(A)

Let $\forall y$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy=0$$

Does this imply $\forall x$, $\forall y$

$$f(x,y)=0\text{?}$$

(B)

Similarly, if $\forall y$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,dy=\text{const}.$$

does this imply $\forall x$, $\forall y$

$$f(x,y)=h(x)$$

for some suitable function $h$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Let $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-y}{1+(x-y)^4}$$

B) Let$$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-y}{1+(x-y)^4}+\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks! XD

Comment: You're welcome   :D